# C Programming- Malloc/Free

Tags: c, malloc, free

So I have a code and when I run it, it hangs when I enter a size greater than 3. When it's exactly 3 it runs smoothly. I narrowed down the problem to malloc and free and I don't know what the problem is. I'm new at this so any help is appreciated.

```
do  //repeatedly ask the user to put a number between 3-9
{ 
 printf("Enter the size of the game board between 3-9: ");
 scanf("%d", &size);
}while(size<3 || size>9);

if((board = (char***)malloc(sizeof(char**)*size))==NULL)
  printf("Memory Allocation failed\n");
  for(i=0; i<size; i++)
  {
    if((board[i] = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*size))==NULL)
     printf("Memory Allocation failed\n");
     for(j=0; j<size; j++)
     {
       if((board[i][j] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*4))==NULL)  
         printf("Memory Allocation failed\n");
         strcpy(board[i][j], "Go");
     }   
 } 
/*************Some random code ***********/ 

free(board);
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
 free(board[i]);
 for(j=0;j<size;j++)
   free(board[i][j]);
}
```

Comment: The order of `free()` should be in exact reverse order of `malloc()`.

Comment: When you use 'free(board[i]);' you actually lose the pointer to the memory you have allocated so you can't use 'free(board[i][j]);'. Use free(board[i]); after the second for.

Comment: @Als: It doesn't have to be in the *exact* reverse order.  If you have an array of 3 pointers, you can `malloc` them in the order 0, 1, 2, then `free` them in the same order.  You just can't `free` a pointer before `free`ing what it points to.

Comment: @KeithThompson: True, It doesn't have to, but I consider it a good practice rather advice especially with multidimensional arrays for new users.Though it abstracts the purpose and the real reason which you quoted, it works flawlessly abstracting the details.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you access `board` after you `free`d it. You should release memory in exactly the reverse order that you `malloc` it.

An alternative approach is that you can allocate all the memory you need in a whole, like

```
 char ***board = NULL;
 char  **rows  = NULL;
 char   *data  = NULL;

 if((board = (char***)malloc(sizeof(char**)*size))==NULL)
  printf("Memory Allocation failed\n");
 if((rows = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*size*size))==NULL)
     printf("Memory Allocation failed\n");
 if((data = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*size*size*4))==NULL)  
     printf("Memory Allocation failed\n");

 for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
     int board_offset = i * size;
     board[i] = rows[board_offset];
     for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
         int row_offset = board_offset + j;
         rows[row_offset] = data[row_offset * 4]；
         stcpy(data[row_offset * 4], "GO");
     }
 }

 free(board);
 free(rows);
 free(data);
```

Comment: hey just have a question. Is it common to check for malloc failure? It almost never happens (unless you corrupt memory or actually run out of it) and I believe it will be adding a considerable expense to if() check every malloc.

Comment: @Lefteris Agree, and I seldom check it to be frank. I just follow the style from  original post:). However, it is necessary for robust code I think.

Comment: Oh I did not notice that he did so in the OP too. Nice to see you agree. Well it depends on what you mean by robust code. I mean if I was to if() check every malloc I guess using another language would be better :P

Comment: @Lefteris: Not necessarily, you could simply wrap `malloc` in a function that exits on error, you'll still only be calling one function to allocate memory, it'll just have a different name. You shouldn't continue the way the OP does if `malloc` fails.

Comment: @AusCBloke Yes ofcourse you can wrap it in a function or even make a neat macro out of it but this is the point I am trying to make. You are adding additional function calling overhead to every malloc call. It all depends on where you wanna set the tradeoff between efficiency and safer programming I suppose.
I might have been checking malloc if I had gotten more failed malloc calls, but in the systems I have worked in malloc only failed if I had made a programming error before and corrupted memory. How would you handle a malloc failure in a real program other than just quit?

Comment: @Lefteris: You should check `malloc()` for error **always**, It gives you error only on corrupting something is a *myth*, it might give you error for any reason,the function doesnt give you an assurance of *when* & *why* it can fail, but it gives you the assurance that *whenever* it fails it will return `NULL`. *How would you handle a malloc failure in a real program other than just quit?* You can have alternate memory management schemes where if `malloc()` fails one might allocate memory through some other alternate mechanism

Comment: Checking for malloc failure isn't nearly as common as it should be.  As @Als says, you should **always** check for `malloc()` failure, even if the response is just to abort the program.

Comment: Additionally, since this wasn't tagged C++, C experts recommend not casting the return value of `malloc()` as it's not necessary in C and can hide an error if you forget to `#include <stdlib.h>` I know nobody ever forgets something so simple, but I still do...

Comment: @AI hey thanks for the input. I suppose then that if an alternate memory management scheme does not exist then there is no option other than quitting. And if it is for debugging purposes you could have a macro wrap of malloc that does the check which prints out where the failure occured (line and function). That way you can always check malloc when in the development stage of the project but for the shipping code just remove the checks. This is what I currently do. Sorry to be using comments to ask this but what do you think of this approach?

Comment: @Lefteris: The problem with your approach is that it *assumes*, if `malloc()` doesnt fail on your debug build it won't fail on the release build either.No, its not true.It *may*! So,What happens if does? Your program goes on further and gives a abrupt crash,not a very desirable behavior IMO.You **must** check for `malloc` failure even in release builds, Don't consider it an overhead,it's how `malloc` is meant to be used.If you think of performance, profile your code and find bottlenecks then fix them,ignorying `malloc` error handling for performance is a pre-optimization & IMO a dangerous one.

Comment: Hmm thanks for your opinion. I can see your point and I appreciate taking the time to detail your logic behind the opinion. I will definitely consider it. Good thing with tge approach in my projects is that it's just a matter of redefining the macro for release builds.

Comment: @Lefteris, just to give it a call, I consider the check of the return of `malloc` a pre-optimization, especically if it results in such awful code as was given by the OP. Assigning the return of `malloc` inside an `if` expression is really bad style and distracts starters like this one from learning more important things and from structuring their code correctly.

Comment: @JensGustedt thanks for the feedback Jens I really appreciate it. I believe that having a wrapping macro which basically lets you change how you call malloc depending on your decision is a good approach since you basically have a choice and changing it is just a matter of editing a line of code. It's the best of both worlds I suppose.  

But having an if() check inside your code in every malloc certainly makes the code look ugly :P